# How do I know I am still on track for the achievements?

Tags: achievements, deus-ex-human-revolution

I am trying to get the pacifist and stealth achievements right now, but I am unsure how to track those achievements. For example: something exploded (a bot I think) shoving a guard into electrified water, killing him. I did not kill him, but he is still dead. How do I know if I would still get the achievement?

Comment: Some games have an option in the menu to look at your achievements, (L4D has tracking on how many zombies you have killed, how many missions you have completed on expert etc.), while others just provide hints at the end of the mission you have completed a certain task (Dishonoured has a little checkbox saying "Never seen" or "nobody killed"). I can't say which is available, or even if any are in Deus-Ex unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way knowing that. Only thing what you can do is to check each body and if someone died by any indirect action of you, the achievement is void and you have to reload an earlier save.

Source: I have the achievement.

Comment: Forum discussion pretty much confirming it: http://steamcommunity.com/app/238010/discussions/0/684839199596844509/

Comment: Interestingly, I had some bodies that I assured were just unconscious. When revisiting them later they had the skull icon for being dead, without me directly killing them. I got the achievements in that playthrough.

Comment: That just happens sometimes, but shouldn't affect the achievement. It counts how you took them down, not what happened later with the body. See strategy section on the wiki: http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Pacifist